# bash sorting -g for scientific notation (E values)

Tags: sorting

I tried `sort` in bash using the `-g` option. I got the following output for `sort -g name.dat`:

```
1.2978025974026E+15  1.2800000000000E-28 3.1000000000000E-29 
1.3565266968326E+13  3.9650000000000E-26 1.0000000000000E-29 
1.3879277777778E+14  2.5900000000000E-27 6.6000000000000E-28 
2.4176806451613E+14 .........................................
```

Only the first few digits are sorted (e.g., `1.29 < 1.35 < 1.38`), but the order isn't actually correct because the scientific notation exponent (`E+15`) is being ignored.

I also tried `sort -k 1 -n name.dat` and `sort -k 1 -g name.dat`, but those don't work either. Changing the `E` to `e` also doesn't work.